# Anyone know the font on this Dustsilver keybord?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

If not is there maby some with a similar feeling or vibe as this one?
Ive tried myfonts.com and whatfontis.com but neither worked.[image: Dustsilver lilac keybord]

Comment: this is an 8-bit game style font that has been cleaned up so it does not look pixelated. Might be custom.

Answer (score -1):

This should be it, let me know if it's ok: https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Exo

Comment: It's good for me, thanks!